# AWS OPENVPN- Generate OVPN FIle Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect my Linux Server (openVPN Client) to OpenVPN Access Server (AWS OpenVPN Linux Appliance).

Found instructions: https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/182-how-to-connect-to-access-server-with-linux-clients.html

However seeing that Linux Server(openVPN Client) doesn't have  a browser to create the ovpn file, I am wondering how I would generate the file ?

I did find this to create a CA using easy-rsa, but the AWS OpenVPN appliance doesn't have the openvpn folder as described:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/09/openvpn-setup

I have access to the OPENVPN Admin/Config page, I just can't seem to  figure out how to generate a OVPN file for a Linux Server (openvpn client)? P.S yes I have installed openvpn client on  Linux Server (openvpn client).

Comment: Are you trying to configure the OpenVPN client (on your Linux box) or the OpenVPN server on AWS?

Comment: configure the linux box as the client